# Arquivo .one do one note não abre no windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1, xaml, onedrive

Tenho um app **Windows Phone 8.1** que acessa o OneDrive após autenticação, tenho acesso a todos os arquivos/pastas e subpastas da conta logada.
Estou com um erro ao tentar abrir o app nativo do one note após chamar minha `Task OpenFile`.

Segue erro:

> Can't open file There is a problem with this file and OneNote can't
>   open it

Todos os arquivos do tipo: `.docx/` `.xlsx/` `.pptx` estão abrindo os apps nativos conforme esperado.

Alguém já passou por esse mesmo problema?

```
public async Task OpenFile (IItem fileItem)
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileItem.Name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (Stream outputStream = Task.Run(() => writeStream.AsStreamForWrite()).Result)
        {                
            Stream downloadStream = await DownloadFileAsync(fileItem);

            await downloadStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        }

        var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileItem.Name);

        var options = new LauncherOptions() { DisplayApplicationPicker = true };
        await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(filerun, options);
    }

    public async Task<Stream> DownloadFileAsync(IItem file)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        File fileDownload;

        fileDownload = file as File;

        stream = await fileDownload.DownloadAsync();

        return stream;
    }
```